# Kotlin compatibility with JavaFXPorts

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, javafx-8, javafxports

I would like to build a JavaFX Android app with [JavaFXPorts](https://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/) and Kotlin code. Is it possible to use Kotlin in a JavaFXPorts project? Here's my example Gradle (version 5.6.4) project:

> Note: Problem with this code is the Kotlin Runtime... Is there any way to bundle everything in the executable Jar and Apk?

```
.
├── app
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── android
│   │   │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── kotlin
│   │           └── com.example
│   │               └── App.kt
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── build.gradle.kts
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

**./settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.javafxports.jfxmobile") {
                useModule("org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "app"
include(":app")
```

**./build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61" apply false
    id("org.javafxports.jfxmobile") version "1.3.18" apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**./app/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.javafxports.jfxmobile")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.App"
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = "src/android/AndroidManifest.xml"
        applicationPackage = application.mainClassName
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        compileSdkVersion = "28"
        targetSdkVersion = "28"
        minSdkVersion = "19"
    }
}
```

**./app/src/android/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    <application android:label="App" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:label="App" android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.example.App"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**./app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/App.kt**

```
@file:JvmName("App")
package com.example

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.stage.Screen
import javafx.stage.Stage

class App : Application() {
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage?) {
        val content = Label("Hello")
        val root = StackPane(content)
        val bounds: Rectangle2D = Screen.getPrimary().visualBounds
        val scene = Scene(root, bounds.width, bounds.height)
        primaryStage?.scene = scene
        primaryStage?.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is working and what not? If you could add a tarball of the project, I could take a look.

Comment: For reference: [JavaFXPorts](https://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports).

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will probably experience some pain along the way, my suggestion is to go with TornadoFx which is Kotlin UI framework built on top of JavaFx. And it is really nice

Here is the [integration guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Integration.html)

Comment: Indeed, TornadoFx plays very well with kotlin. The [guide](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/2_Setting_Up.html) describes how to setup gradle to worth with OpenJFX